# Running Windows Mobile apps on Desktop

Tags: windows-10, windows-mobile

Now that Windows 10 and Windows Mobile 10 are one and the same, I question if it is possible to find and install Windows Mobile apps on a desktop that runs Windows 10.

The Windows Store won't allow me to find apps designed for Windows Mobile while on my Windows 10 desktop. Is it possible to alter my desktop (maybe a key in registry) to allow me to search for and install apps made for Windows Mobile?

Comment: `Windows 10` and `Windows Mobile 10` are not the same operating system.  An application must be a UWP and be released for both `Windows 10` and `Windows Mobile 10` for it to run on both operating systems.  **"is it possible to alter your registry to let "** - Nope

Comment: http://betanews.com/2015/07/10/leaked-tool-lets-you-download-windows-phone-apps-on-a-pc/ Also, you *may* be able to achieve what you want with a Windows Phone Emulator

Answer (score 0):

You cant install the windows apps directly on windows phone, because windows can also run .exe files but windows phone can not. You can only run a windows app on windows phone if its a universal app and that to by installing through store.

Answer (score -1):

No, as both Windows10 and Windows Mobile 10 both are having different operating system. We cannot use both of them in one. 
There should be an application in which both of these can work.

Comment: Except UWP can work on both `Windows 10` and `Windows Mobile 10` and are located in the Windows Store.